# Resolving imports not found errors in Flex/Adobe Flash Builder

Tags: flex4, flash-builder4.5

I am very new to Flex/Adobe FlashBuilder and I am running into an "import not found" error. Coming from a Java background, I understand this is more of a question of importing the equivalent of *.jar files in Flex/Flash. But how exactly I should go about resolving this, I am unaware.

Anybody want to help and get some points :) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're a beginner probably everything you import is included is Flex framework or is made by you. If you import your own classes remember to preserve package in their names (if the come from different package). Check classes names for spelling errors.

When using class in code you can use content assist (`Ctrl+Space`), then imports will be added automatically.

You can also check what quickfix lightbulb says (it's the same as in Eclipse as FBuilder is based on it).

You can make your question much better by including the code that causes the error.